# Glassfish server does not start _JAVA_OPTIONS

Tags: netbeans, server, glassfish

this error appears when I try to start the server in netbeans

Initial heap size set to a larger value than the maximum heap size
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=192m; support was removed in 8.0
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms1024M

How can i solve it? [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZiAq.jpg)

Comment: What version of Netbeans are you running and can you provide screen shots?

Comment: The version of netbeans is 8.0.2 @Dinnerspy

Comment: What it the max heap size in Netbeans set to? Also try J-XX:PermSize instead of MaxPermSize

Comment: I don't know how the max heap size is set how can I see? 

Where can I try J-XX: Permasize? @Dinnerspy

Comment: It should be in the config file located in C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\etc . find a line like this netbeans_default_options="......." the heap size will look like this -J-Xmx<memorysize>

Comment: -J-XX: PermSize = 32m this is written in the file. What do I have to do now? @Dinnerspy

Comment: Try change it to 192m

Comment: At server startup the error is always the same @Dinnerspy

Comment: Lets try bumping up glassdish's heap size. go to C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml. inside it look for Xmx. Edit it the number to be 2048. if this dose not work change it back.

Comment: Thanks now it works!

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you need to edit glassfishes heap size. As of now the max heap size it less then the min heap size.

To do this edit the domain.xml it usialy will be located in  C:\Program Files\glassfish-4.1.1\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml

Inside it look for Xmx. Edit it the number to be 2048 this increases the max heap size to about 2 Gigabits. As your min size is about 1 Gigabit.